# I need to call .Init for a nugget package

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I started coding on Xamarin.Forms a while ago and everything was cool until I needed a round button. I found a [very cool nugget package](https://github.com/wilsonvargas/ButtonCirclePlugin) online and installed it using package manager console (I'm using VStudio 2019 if that matters). The only problem is that I "need to call `ButtonCircleRenderer.Init()`  on each platform" and I have no clue on how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Andorid you can call it inside MainActivity.cs from `OnCreate()`

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
...
     ButtonCircleRenderer.Init();
...
}
```

On iOS you can call it inside AppDelegate.cs from `FinishedLaunching()`

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication application, NSDictionary launchOptions)
{
...
     ButtonCircleRenderer.Init();
...
}
```